# (Done) Req: Reopen "Possibly Inappropriate Question on Performance Review"

Tags: discussion

[Possibly Inappropriate Question on Performance Review](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/196653/possibly-inappropriate-question-on-performance-review)

The question was closed for being opinion based, where the question was very clear.

4 Reopen votes as of this post.

Answer (score 2):

I would not have used my mod powers to do it, but since it was already 4 votes in favor, I was happy to be number 5. Reopened.